# Perl: how to expand nested variable names

Tags: regex, perl

So far I have a text config file that has variables in it like this:

```
foo=something
bar=${foo}
```

When processing it in Perl, I replace the variables with a regex like this:

```
s/(?<!\\)\$\{\s*([^\}\s]+(\s+[^\}\s]+)*)\s*\}/_replacement( $1 )/ge;
```

where _replacement() knows how to look up existing values.

Now I'd like to be able to extend the syntax of the text file so I can do this recursively, like this:

```
platform=x86
foo_x86=somepc
foo_arm=somedevice
bar=${foo_${platform}}
```

where when processing the last line, "${platform}" first gets replaced with "x86", and the resulting "${foo_x86}" then gets replaced with "somepc".

I'm having trouble with extending my regex: I can't quite seem to find a way to match the } with the correct {. (Greedy won't work because a string might be "${a}${b}", and non-greedy will mismatch.)

Ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately nesting things is a place where you're starting to push the limits of regex - it's not well suited to recursive parsing like that. But handing it off to the `replace` sub, and running that recursively might do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub expand {
   my ($vars, $s) = @_;
   $s =~ s{
      (
         \$\{
         (
            (?> [^\$\}]
            |   \$ (?! \{ )
            |   (?1)
            )++
         )
         \}
      )
   }{
      my $expanded = expand($vars, $2);
      $vars->{$expanded} // "\${$expanded}"    # /
   }xeg;
   return $s;
}

my $vars = {};
while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   my ($key, $val) = split(/=/, $_, 2);
   $vars->{$key} = expand($vars, $val);
}

print($vars->{bar}, "\n");

__DATA__
platform=x86
foo_x86=somepc
foo_arm=somedevice
bar=${foo_${platform}}
```

Comment: Which teaches that there always 8.3 more things to know about regexes than I do know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your input file is very similar to the format supported by [AppConfig](https://metacpan.org/release/AppConfig) which would also let's you extend the same syntax to your command line or other inputs.

```
use AppConfig;

# create a new AppConfig object
my $config = AppConfig->new();

# define a variable
$config->set( 'foo', 'bar' );

# read configuration file
my $filename = 'your.conf';
$config->file( $filename );
```